# icefaces calendar images are not displayed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am using icefaces popup calendar. My problem is that the images could not be found. It seems to be a known bug.

[image: Calendar in Safari]

So what now? This is what the icefaces api told me about the selectInputDate:

imageDir:

> Set directory for location of the button images. Deprecated. Use
>   styleClass instead. The style class name for a button is made up of
>   the styleClass name plus a predefined name. For example: with a
>   styleClass name of "myCalendar", the button class names would be:
>   myCalendarMovePrev, myCalendarMoveNext, myCalendarOpenPopup,
>   myCalendarClosePopup. Override the images with the background-image
>   property.

But overwriting the background-image does not work because the generated input field is of type image which uses "src".

```
<ice:selectInputDate styleClass="iceCal" id="detailFrist" value="#{ticketDetailListBean.ticket.frist}" label="Fällig bis" labelPosition="left" requiredIndicator="(*)" required="true" indicatorPosition="right"
                renderAsPopup="true" validator="de.xxxxx.validator.TicketFristValidator">

    <f:converter converterId="de.xxxxx.converter.MultiDateConverter" />     
    <f:attribute name="pattern1" value="dd.MM.yyyy" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern2" value="ddMMyyyy" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern3" value="dd.MM" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern4" value="ddMM" />
</ice:selectInputDate>

.iceCalMovePrev {
    background-image:url(../images/icons_opensource/arrow-down.png);
    background-repeat:none;
}

.iceCalMoveNext {
    background-image:url(../images/icons_opensource/arrow-down.png);
    background-repeat:none;
}

.iceCalMoveOpenPopup {
    background-image:url(../images/icons_opensource/arrow-down.png);
    background-repeat:none;
}

.iceCalClosePopup {
    background-image:url(../images/icons_opensource/arrow-down.png);
    background-repeat:none;
}
```

I inspected the code with Safari:

[image]

If i open the calendar with google chrome, it looks so:

[image]

So what can I do t display the images correctly and easily?

Update :

At moment I use the deprecated method. First I need to add the Resource Servlet, declared in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.CompatResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The Icon Bug is still alive... but now no error and no icon is displayed, so here is the part of using the deprecated method:

```
imageDir="/xmlhttp/css/rime/css-images/"
```

That is looking so now... :

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using the calendar from the compatibility-components and not the one from the newer ACE-Components?

Comment: Oh hm no.. thanks for that hint. I lost sight of.. :)